# Snake lemma for $R$-modules. Help with $\ker$ maps, not connecting hom.

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, diagram-chasing

In [Construction of the maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma#Construction_of_the_maps) they say that the construction of the kernel/cokernel maps comes from the commutativity of the diagram:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
& & A @>{f}>> B @>{g}>>C @>>> 0 \\
& @VV{a}V & @VV{b}V & @VV{c}V \\
0 @>>> A' @>{f'}>> B' @>{g'}>> C' \\
\end{CD}
$$

Define $\hat{f} = f\mid_{\ker a}$.  I want to show that $\hat{f}(A) \subset \ker b$.  So that $\ker a \xrightarrow{\hat{f}} \ker b$ exists.

Let $x \in \ker{a}$, then $b\hat{f}(x) = bf(x) = f'a(x) = 0$ so that $f(x) \in \ker b$.  Next, if $\hat{g}$ is defined similarly, then I want to show exactness or $\ker \hat{g} = \text{im} \hat{f}$. First, $\ker \hat{g} \supset \text{im} \hat{f}$ or $\hat{g}\hat{f} = 0$.

I don't see how to show this.

We know that $\ker g = \text{im} f$ so that $\ker g \cap \ker b = \text{im}f \cap \ker b \supset \text{im} \hat{f}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion of $\mathrm{ker} c$ into $C$ is a monomorphism, so $\hat g\hat f=0$ because $gf=0$.